# Doubts about proving something is a bijection by the existence of a well-defined inverse

Tags: group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation

So I am reading a proof for the following proposition:

**Proposition.** Any subgroup of $S_n$ contains either no odd permutations or exactly half.

*Proof.*
If $S_n$ has at least one odd permutation $\tau$, then there exists a bijection between the odd and even permutations by $\sigma \mapsto \sigma\tau$. This is a bijection since $\sigma \mapsto \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is a well defined inverse.
So there are as many odd permutations as even permutations.

---

I believe I understand what this proof is saying, but I have a few uncertainties, mainly about how we have shown that this bijection exists.

What I am getting from this is that the existence of such an inverse function shows the surjectivity of the original function, while it being well-defined shows that the original function is injective. Thus, the original function is bijective.

What I have doubts about are:

- What about the case where there are multiple odd permutations? Using only one of the odd permutations, how are we sure that we are able to get a function that maps all even permutations to odd permutations? Applying the inverse function to an even permutation, can we really get all the odd permutations, including the ones we are not using to compose in the function?
- How are we verifying that $\sigma \to \sigma\tau^{-1}$ is well defined? Are we simply saying: choose some even permutations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ such that $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$. Applying $\tau^{-1}$ to both sides, we see that: $\sigma_1 \tau^{-1} = \sigma_2 \tau^{-1}$. So, the inverse is well-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On *any* group $G$, if you take *any* element $h\in G$, then the map $r_h\colon G\longrightarrow G$ defined by $r_h(g)=gh$ is a bijection from $G$ onto $G$, precisely because $r_{h^{-1}}$ is an inverse of $r_h$. Since it is a bijection, in particular it is surjective. So, in your specific situation, you will get all odd elements simply because you will get *every* of the subgroup.
- Where is your doubt? For each $\sigma$ in the subgroup, you consider the element $\sigma\tau^{-1}$. Why would it *not* be well-defined? You associate with each element of the subgroup one (and only one) element of the subgroup. So, it is a well-defined map from the subgroup into itself.